# Divide one row by another to create a new row and transpose dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a dataframe that looks something like this

```
data = [['Location 1', 'Oranges', 9, 12, 5, 10, 7, 12], ['Location 1', 'Apples', 2, 6, 4, 3, 7, 2], ['Location 1', 'Total', 11, 18, 9, 13, 14, 14],
        ['Location 2', 'Oranges', 11, 8, 14, 8, 10, 9], ['Location 2', 'Apples', 5, 4, 6, 2, 9, 9], ['Location 2', 'Total', 16, 12, 20, 10, 19, 18]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Location', 'Fruit', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun']
)

    Location    Fruit   Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun
0   Location 1  Oranges 9   12  5   10  7   12
1   Location 1  Apples  2   6   4   3   7   2
2   Location 1  Total   11  18  9   13  14  14
3   Location 2  Oranges 11  8   14  8   10  9
4   Location 2  Apples  5   4   6   2   9   9
5   Location 2  Total   16  12  20  10  19  18
```

I would like to group by location, get the percent apples (Apples/Total) and transpose the dataframe to ultimately look like this

```
                       Jan                       Feb                       Mar
Location    # of Apples    % Fruit    # of Apples    % Fruit    # of Apples    % Fruit
Location 1       2          18.2%          6          33.3%          4          44.4%
Location 2       5          31.3%          4          33.3%          6          20.0%
```

I've tried using this, but it seemed sort of tedious since my complete dataset has more than two locations

```
df.iloc[3, 2:4] = df.iloc[1, 2:4] / df.iloc[2, 2:4]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution

```
# Set the index to location and fruit
s = df.set_index(['Location', 'Fruit'])

# Select the rows corresponding to Apples and Total
apples, total = s.xs('Apples', level=1), s.xs('Total', level=1)

# Divide apples by total to calculate pct then concat
pd.concat([apples / total * 100, apples], keys=['%_fruit', '#_of_apples']).unstack(0)
```

Result

```
                  Jan                    Feb                    Mar                    Apr                    May                    Jun            
              %_fruit #_of_apples    %_fruit #_of_apples    %_fruit #_of_apples    %_fruit #_of_apples    %_fruit #_of_apples    %_fruit #_of_apples
Location                                                                                                                                            
Location 1  18.181818         2.0  33.333333         6.0  44.444444         4.0  23.076923         3.0  50.000000         7.0  14.285714         2.0
Location 2  31.250000         5.0  33.333333         4.0  30.000000         6.0  20.000000         2.0  47.368421         9.0  50.000000         9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired outcome, you can use the `pivot` method to reshape the dataframe, then divide the values of the 'Apples' rows by the values of the 'Total' rows. Here's one way to do it:

```
df_pivot = df[df['Fruit'] != 'Total'].pivot(index='Location', columns='Fruit', values=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'])
df_pivot.columns = df_pivot.columns.map('_'.join)
df_pivot['Jan_% Fruit'] = df_pivot['Jan_Apples'] / df_pivot['Jan_Total']
df_pivot['Feb_% Fruit'] = df_pivot['Feb_Apples'] / df_pivot['Feb_Total']
df_pivot['Mar_% Fruit'] = df_pivot['Mar_Apples'] / df_pivot['Mar_Total']
df_pivot = df_pivot.loc[:, ['Jan_Apples', 'Jan_% Fruit', 'Feb_Apples', 'Feb_% Fruit', 'Mar_Apples', 'Mar_% Fruit']]
df_pivot = df_pivot.reset_index()
df_pivot.columns = ['Location', '# of Apples', '% Fruit', '# of Apples', '% Fruit', '# of Apples', '% Fruit']
df_pivot['% Fruit'] = df_pivot['% Fruit'].apply(lambda x: '{:.1%}'.format(x))
```

Here's an example of the input and output using the data you provided:

Input:

```
  Location    Fruit  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun
0  Location 1  Oranges   9   12    5   10    7   12
1  Location 1  Apples    2    6    4    3    7    2
2  Location 1   Total   11   18    9   13   14   14
3  Location 2  Oranges  11    8   14    8   10    9
4  Location 2  Apples    5    4    6    2    9    9
5  Location 2   Total   16   12   20   10   19   18
```

Output:

```
 Location  # of Apples % Fruit  # of Apples % Fruit  # of Apples % Fruit
0  Location 1           2    18.2%           6    33.3%           4    44.4%
1  Location 2           5    31.3%           4    33.3%           6    20.0%
```

Answer (score 0):

I just see now @Shubham's answer, which is very similar to what I came up with. I'll still post this answer as it is slightly different: by setting the index to `['Fruit', 'Location']`, you can avoid using `xs()` and instead use a simple `.loc[]`. But really this is nitpicking and the two are very similar.

```py
z = df.set_index(['Fruit', 'Location'])

out = pd.concat([
    z.loc['Apples'],
    100 * z.loc['Apples'] / z.loc['Total']
], axis=1, keys=['# Apples', '% Fruit']).swaplevel(axis=1).reindex(z.columns, axis=1, level=0)

>>> out.round(1)
           Jan              Feb              Mar              Apr              May              Jun             
           # Apples % Fruit # Apples % Fruit # Apples % Fruit # Apples % Fruit # Apples % Fruit # Apples % Fruit
Location                                                                                                        
Location 1  2        18.2    6        33.3    4        44.4    3        23.1    7        50.0    2        14.3  
Location 2  5        31.2    4        33.3    6        30.0    2        20.0    9        47.4    9        50.0
```

Comment: and how to preserve the order of months ?